# Angularjs component state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

Hello I have few questions with using components in state. So i have tried doing ui-routing using templates and it works fine. but instead when i try to route it to a component, i get this error.

in my app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                component: 'home'
        });
}]);
```

and in my index.html

```
 <html ng-app="app">
    <head>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="Content/lib/angularjs/Chart.js"></script>
        <script src="Content/lib/angularjs/angular-chart.js"></script>
        <script src="Content/app/components/home.js"></script>
        <script src="Content/app/app.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/app/components/redditAnalyzer.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <a ui-sref="home">click me</a>
        <div ui-view></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and in my home.html

```
<body>

    "some stuffs"

</body>
```

and in my home.js

```
angular.module('app', ['chart.js'])
    .component('home', {
        templateUrl: 'Content/app/components/home.html',
        bindings: {},
        controller: ['$http',
            function ($http) {
                var vm = this;

"some more stuffs"

            }]
    });
```

but when i click on click me in my index.html, i get this error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/unpr?p0=homeDirectiveProvider%20%3C-%20homeDirective
    at angular.js:88
    at angular.js:4826
    at Object.d [as get] (angular.js:4981)
    at angular.js:4831
    at Object.d [as get] (angular.js:4981)
    at getComponentBindings (angular-ui-router.js:sourcemap:8144)
    at TemplateFactory.makeComponentTemplate (angular-ui-router.js:sourcemap:8135)
    at Ng1ViewConfig.getTemplate (angular-ui-router.js:sourcemap:7938)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular-ui-router.js:sourcemap:9719)
    at angular.js:1385 "<div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">"
```

what am i doing wrong?
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering the  module named `"app"` twice. A second module with same name will overwrite the first

Only use the dependency injection array on one of them when they have the same name. When there is no dependency array argument it acts as a getter not setter

Change:

```
// register new module with dependencies
angular.module('app', ['ui.router']).config...
// register new module with dependencies ... but will overwrite the first due to same name
angular.module('app', ['chart.js']).component...
```

To:

```
// register new module with dependencies
angular.module('app', ['ui.router','chart.js']).config...
// references an existing module to add component to
angular.module('app').component...
```

Also switch order of `<script>` so the module exists before you try to add  component to it

```
<!-- Module created in this file -->
<script src="Content/app/app.js"></script>
<!-- subsequent files can then access existing module -->
<script src="Content/app/components/home.js"></script>
```

Comment: An alternative is to create a different named module with dependencies needed for it like chart.js and inject the second module into the first `"app"` module. All depends on personal preference but also allows taking that module easily to another project if needed